# Python: Perfomance issue in Finding Duplicates in Files Containing Millions of Data

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am writing a detailed file validation script for my project in python 2.7 using core-python APIs. This is for comparing source and target files of another ETL code.
This includes meta data validation,count validation,duplicate check,null check and full data validation line by line. I have completed the script and
its running good for 100k data set(I did some test run on 100k,200k volumes).But the method for duplicate check is running for ever (I mean taking a huge amount of time) if i run with millions of data in. I have debugged the code and found that the below method for duplicvate check is causing the problem.

```
    def dupFind(dup_list=[],output_path=""):
        #dup_list is the list containing duplicates. Actually this is the list of contents of a file line by line as entries
        #output_path is the path to which output records and respective duplicate count of each records are saved as a single file
        #duplicates is a set which contains tuples with two elements each in which first element is the duplicated record and second is the duplicated count

        duplicates=set((x,dup_list.count(x)) for x in filter(lambda rec : dup_list.count(rec)>1,dup_list)) 
        print "time taken for preparing duplicate list is {}".format(str(t1-t0))
        dup_report="{}\dup.{}".format(output_path, int(time.time()))
        print "Please find the duplicate records  in {}".format(dup_report)
        print ""
        with open(dup_report, 'w+') as f:
            f.write("RECORD|DUPLICATE_COUNT\n")
            for line in duplicates:
                f.write("{}|{}\n".format(line[0], line[1]))
```

First I am reading the file and converting it in to a list as given below(its running fast):

```
     with open(sys.argv[1]) as src,open(sys.argv[2]) as tgt:
            src = map(lambda x : x.strip(),list(src))
            tgt = map(lambda x : x.strip(),list(tgt))
```

After that I am applying the  below logic(pseudo code is provided) on both 'src' and 'tgt' lists to find if a file is duplicated or not:

```
    #here output path is passed as a user argument while running the script

    if len(set(tgt)) < len(tgt) then Target  is duplicated and call dupFind function as dupFind(tgt,outputpath)
    if len(set(src)) < len(src) then source is duplicated and call dupFind function as dupFind(src,outputpath)
```

And thus which ever list is duplicated , that will be consumed by the dupFind function and then it will save the duplicated records and respective count
in to a file in output path in the format 'dup.epochtime'. If I run the entire file validation script for millions of records (even 1 M ), its running for ever.
When I debugged on function , the below particular line is causing the performance issue.

```
    #here using filter() , I am filtering out duplicates records alone from the duplicated list
    #then creating a tuple over it containg a pair of values in which first element is the duplicated record and second is the duplicated count

    duplicates=set((x,dup_list.count(x)) for x in filter(lambda rec : dup_list.count(rec)>1,dup_list))
```

output duplicates file looks like this :

```
    RECORD|DUPLICATE_COUNT
    68881,2014-07-19 00:00:00.0,2518,PENDING_PAYMENT|2
    68835,2014-05-02 00:00:00.0,764,COMPLETE|2
    68878,2014-07-08 00:00:00.0,6753,COMPLETE|2
    68834,2014-05-01 00:00:00.0,6938,COMPLETE|2
```

Can any one please help me to modify the logic or write a new logic so that I can deal with millions of records at a time.In my project ,
files up to  40M or  50M are there.

Comment: Using `list.count` in a loop is quadratic time. I'd start there. Also, be careful with mutable default arguments

Comment: As an aside, this: `rc = map(lambda x : x.strip(),list(src))` is needlessly inefficient. No need for `list(src)`, and for that matter, you can just use `rc = map(str.strip, src)` or just `rc = [s.strip() for s in src]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  It worked and I have validated using 10 M data now and its done execution with in seconds. Also I have made the other changes you have pointed out. Thank you :)

Comment: Read about mutable default arguments and why they might not behave how you would expect here: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Answer (score 1):

You are using `list.count` in a loop. This is very inefficient. Instead, do a single pass to get the counts, then another pass to filter on these counts. Linear vs quadratic time. So, using the fast `collections.Counter` object:

```
from collections import Counter
def dupFind(dup_list=(),output_path=""):

    counts = Counter(dup_list)
    duplicates = {(x, c) for x, c in counts.iteritems() if c > 1}
    ...
```

Note, I switched your default `dup_list` argument to an empty tuple instead of an empty list. Mutable default arguments can cause bugs if you don't understand how they work.

The above solution does require auxiliary space, but it should be pretty fast, a `collections.Counter` is essentially a `dict` optimized for counting.

Comment: It woked like charm!! Thanks a ton

Comment: I am wondering what is the difference between  Counter.iteritems() and Counter.items() ? I can iterate through both !!

Comment: @akhilpathirippilly in python 2, `.items` produces a list, which is inefficient (unless you actually want a list). `iteritems` produces an iterator, so it is constant space (and doesn't require extra time to materialize the list). In Python 3, `.items` no longer returns a list, but a set-like *view* of the items, which doesn't require auxiliary space, and is similarly efficiently iterable. it is the equivalent of python 2 `viewitems`

Comment: Got it . One more thing, Why I have given a mutable default list because , I need the function  to display the argument type as list where ever it is calling. In Java , we  need to mention the data type as list for the function parameter, so where ever you call it , it will display the argument type to be passed as 'list'. How we can achieve the same here?

Comment: @akhilpathirippilly python doesn't have typed arguments, it is a dynamic language. There is no argument type. Now, Python 3.6+ introduced type-hinting. You can use `mypy` as a third-party static type-checker to enforce this before runtime, but Python itself doesn't enforce this, and if you want to, you have to check if the argument is a list yourself.

Comment: @akhilpathirippilly so, it doesn't seem like you need a default argument at all. If you do actually want one, the idiom in python is to use `def foo(x=None): ...` then in the body, check `if x is None: x = []`. But if you simply want IDE support, just type-hinting would work, although, it isn't really fully fledged for Python 2.

Comment: Got your point on typed arguments in Python. Last and final doubt, But say if use a mutable list, what all areas, my code going to suffer? It will be good if you can suggest me some link or web notes on this topic ? Thanks a lot for your patience to clarify my doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference from `src` and `tgt`, so I present here a solution for a generic list. I think this solution will speed up the scan a bit. For more speed up I will try to use pypy or c.

```
import sys

def dup_find(sequence, marker=object()):
    prev = marker
    c = 1 
    for item in sequence:
        if item == prev:
            c += 1
        else:
            if c > 1:
                yield prev, c
            prev = item
            c = 1 
    if c > 1:
        yield prev, c

def print_dup(sequence, output):
    for item, count in dup_find(sequence):
        output.write('%s|%s\n' % (item, count))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fp: 
    lines = sorted(map(str.strip, fp))
if len(set(lines)) < len(lines):
    print_dup(lines, sys.stdout)
```

Comment: I would also check the data set, see how often there are files with duplicates and benchmark the code with or without the check on the length.